# Open Api documentation for a single endpoint multiple posts request

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to have Swagger/Open Api documentation for my single endpoint API.

My single endpoint looks like

> POST: http://localhost/api/v1/process

the post body determines the logical path and response schema

`Body1: {"jsonClass": "AnimalsRankedByLifeSpan"}
Response1: schema-1`

`Body2: {"jsonClass": "AnimalsInRegion", "region":"Africa", "type":"lions"}
Response2: schema-2`

Expectation from documentation: Each jsonClass is listed as a separate call in swagger (or any other) and I can use the spec to get all the jsonClasses supported.

Doesnt look like, swagger supports this kind of design. If it does, please point me to examples.

Are there any other Api documentation frameworks I can use for providing request-response documentation for each kind of jsonClass supported?

Comment: I don t this is possible without tweaking swagger-ui.

Comment: Possibly related: [Swagger: variant schema shape dependant on field value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46557096/113116)

Answer (score 8):

OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 do not have a way to map different request schemas to different response schemas within the same operation. Here is the corresponding feature request: [Support an operation to have multiple specifications per path (e.g. multiple POST operation per path)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/182)

For now, if you use OpenAPI 3.0, you can use `oneOf` to define multiple possible schemas for the request and response. However, you cannot define that `Body1` produces `schema-1` response and `Body2` produces `schema-2` response. You can only document this verbally in the operation `description`.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Body1'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Body2'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/schema-1'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/schema-2'
```