# Swagger UI marking parameters as group

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is it possible to somehow mark properties so that it's understandable which field should be set in SwaggerUI when sending request.

For example we have a route for payments, which has ***payment_type*** property that can hold values like **paypal**, **credit_card**, **crypto**, etc. and based on that field we need to fill different properties like below.

```
{
  "payment": 0,
  "paypal": "test@test.com",
  "cryptocurrency": "test",
  "wallet_address": "test",
  "swift": "test",
  "iban": "test",
  "account_name": "test",
  "bank_name": "test"
}
```

Is it possible to mark them somehow so that they are grouped, like for ***crypto*** **cryptocurrency** and **wallet_address** should be set, while for ***bank transfer*** **swift**, **iban**, **account_name** and **bank_name** should be set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger: variant schema shape dependant on field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557096/swagger-variant-schema-shape-dependant-on-field-value). Related: [Swagger Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27862407/113116), [“discriminator” in polymorphism, OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730295/113116), [OpenAPI documentation for a single endpoint multiple posts request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46250030/113116)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal swagger definition that uses this model? I would like to try incorporating what @Helen mentioned in the the comments... lets see if that makes it understandable which field should be set in SwaggerUI when sending request.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such an option.
We are limited by the [OpenAPI-Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#parameterObject), read the Parameter Object section to see a list of available fields.

Now knowing that limitation not everything is lost, here are a few options:

- You do have `description` that is a good place to add your details.
- You also can go with a [Specification Extension](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#specification-extensions) but that will not be something that the swagger-ui will support by default, if you need the UI to take action on your extension(s) you will need to code it.
- Another option pointed out in the comments by @Helen is using `discriminator` but that is not currently supported by the swagger-ui:
  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2438

Comment: `there is no such an option` - actually `discriminator` can be used for this kind of scenario, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575120/113116).

Comment: @helen is that possible for flat structure or just objects?

Comment: @DoubleK What do you mean by "flat structure"?

Comment: @helen by flat I mean
```
{
  "payment": 0,
  "paypal": "test@test.com",
  "cryptocurrency": "test",
  "wallet_address": "test",
  "swift": "test",
  "iban": "test",
  "account_name": "test",
  "bank_name": "test"
}
```
and as object I mean

```
{
 "payment": 0,
 "crypto": {
  "cryptocurrency": "test",
  "wallet_address": "test"
 },
 "bank": {
  "swift": "test",
  "iban": "test",
  "account_name": "test",
  "bank_name": "test"
 }
}
```

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the tip about `discriminator` I personally never used that before ... and I'm struggling to create an example that satisfies the question: > How to make it understandable which field should be set in SwaggerUI when sending request?

Comment: @DoubleK: `discriminator` works for "flat" objects and _may_ work for nested objects too depending on the use case - e.g. model inheritance/composition lets you vary top-level properties, but probably not nested properties. Check out the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46557096/113116) in the linked question - it's very similar to your case, just the property names are different.

Comment: @HelderSepu *"How to make it understandable which field should be set in SwaggerUI when sending request?"* Good question. You can define `discriminator` and model inheritance/composition in the API definition, but Swagger UI currently [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2438) switching input models based on `discriminator`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730295/113116) mentions an alternative documentation renderer that supports `discriminator` - if that's an option.

Comment: @helen that's exactly my problem `but Swagger UI currently does not support switching input models based on discriminator` :(